# Separate data sourse for JUnit

Tags: jdbc, junit, h2, dao

I have JDBC dao (Servlets, not Spring), and i want to set up separate Database H2 for JUnit.

Here is my connections code

```
 public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/library");
            con = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            log.error("Cannot obtain a connection from the pool", ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.info("Error get driver in db! {}", e);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Also one method from DAO

```
 public void delete(User object) throws BaseException {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DBWorker.getDbWorker().getConnection()
                .prepareStatement(UserQueries.DELETE_USER)) {
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, object.getId());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            String errorMessage = "Error delete User " + e.getMessage();
            log.error(errorMessage);
            throw new BaseException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The code `DBWorker.getDbWorker().getConnection()` return singleton object to connect to database.

How can i test thid `delete` method in Junit. I want a separate database for test. In Spring i can do this with two properties files, one for dev, second for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Re-ordered DAO classes. Added constructor

```
private Connection connection;

public AuthorService(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}
```

And in my AbstractFactory i push needed for me connection. So, i can test Service classes with separate Data Source